# Custom post-type child category archive

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

Having a bit of a headache with WordPress at the moment after days of searching for an answer. I have a custom post-type on a new site called videos, and I want series of videos on the site. I decided to use standard categories for organising these videos into the series.

So, my structure goes:

Videos (post-type) -> Series (Category) -> The Making Of (child-category).

In terms of the hierarchy I have no idea which template would allow me to show all the posts from the child category? I've tried so many variations and none seem to work. And yes, I've been looking at the template hierarchy.

Maybe I'm just missing the obvious, but does anyone know what template is needed to show this child-category? I'd hate to have to make a page each time there's a new series to show.

[UPDATE]

So, I've changed over to a custom taxonomy as suggested in the comment below. And I've managed to get the list of posts from my `making-of` category showing up in a list. This uses the `taxonomy-$term.php` template.

This shows in the url `mysite.com/series/making-of/`.

But, I'm struggling to find a way to display all of the different categories from the post-type on a single page. I thought it would use just the `taxonomy.php` file but that doesn't seem to work.

I thought the url would have been `mysite.com/series/`

Comment: category.php should do it. The issue is that it only shows posts where post_type = 'post'. You need to change the post_type to videos. You may be better off creating a custom taxonomy of 'Series' so you can keep your standard Post and custom post type archives separate.

Comment: So, if I made `series` a custom taxonomy, and `the making of` a child of that, which taxonomy template would be used? I'd assume `taxonomy-$tanonomy-$term.php` but I seem to be pretty wrong about these things lol.